# Ajax Live Search, how to put the text into the input form if the search result is only one?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

First, I'd like to tell that I don't know how to code.
I just copy and paste the codes, try a little modify to the codes where most of the time the code not work than work.

So, I copy a Live Search codes from this [link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php) as below.
The html :

```
<div class="search-box">
<form name="search-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input onfocus="myFunction(this)" type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ketik Nama..." />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT/CLEAR" id="myButton" STYLE="visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="result"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

And this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){

            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $("#myButton").click();
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
```

The code works as expected.
But I've been thinking that if there is only one result, I would like to have the code for directly put the result into the input box - something like

```
$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
```

It seems that I need to insert the code like this : (not an actual code)

```
$.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
     resultDropdown.html(data);
       if count(resultDropdown.html(data)) = 1 {
         "put the result to the input-box";
         $("#myButton").click();
         $(this).parent(".result").empty();
       }
```

But I don't know how to write the code.
I've tried to search all over the internet, but I can't find one what  I'm looking for.

Any kind of response would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `backend-search.php` dibikin respon json

Comment: @FSodic, thank you. I will try that. Makasih ya Sodic.